# Match/subset one dataframe based on conditional values in another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
df1=data.frame(A=c(1,2,4,8), B=c(4,3,2,9), C=c(10,11,1,2), D=c(12,40,3,4))
df2=data.frame(A=c(0.5,2.0,0.1,0.3), B=c(1.5,0.5,0.2,0.1), C=c(3.0,1.25,0.5,0.2), D=c(0.7,0.8,0.2,2.0))
```

I want to keep values in df1 that are <= 0.8 in df1 for all columns and `NA`s in the ones that are > 0.8

I tried to find and replace values > 0.8 in df2:

```
df2[df2 >= 0.8] <- NA
```

Then I tried to replace all matching values in df1 with the `NA` in df2 but something like the script below wants columns not dataframes:

```
df1[match(df1, df2==NA)]
```

I want the final dataframe to look like this:

```
df3=data.frame(A=c(1,NA,4,8), B=c(NA,3,2,9), C=c(NA,NA,1,2), D=c(12,40,3,NA))
```

TIA

Comment: `NA` should not be quoted

Comment: @akrun  quotation removal doesn't fix issue or answer question

Comment: Your expected output is not matching the description provided `NA^(df2 > 0.8) * df1`

Comment: @akrun Not trying to be rude, just straight forward, the quotes didn't help anything, it might have been more helpful to add your suggestion to a possible solution. You are correct about my desired outcome so I edited it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: it's okay.  I mentioned that in case you are making a mistake and quoting `NA` can cause some issues in other casses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can directly assign `NA` based on the logical matrix

```
 NA^(df2 > 0.8) * df1
```

or

```
`is.na<-`(df1, df2 > 0.8)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Also, someone removed a comment earlier which also worked df1[df2 > 0.8] <- NA

Answer (score 3):

Use `mapply` like this:

```
as.data.frame(mapply(function(x, y) ifelse(y <= 0.8, x, NA), df1, df2))
```

or

```
replace(df1, df2 > 0.8, NA)
```